# Python server TCP server accessable from anywhere (via external IP, port forwarding is done)

Tags: python, tcp, server, raspberry-pi

I am new here, so please, don't be angry if I am stupid - but I don't know about it.
I would like to make a python TCP server, which can be accessed from anywhere via external (public) IP. I have done simple server (it works) in local network from this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiVVYfgDolU
The client sends string and the server sends back that string but with uppercase.

Now I want to do the same but accessable from anywhere. I read a lot about it. I have Raspberry Pi, where I set up static IP address and I did the port forward (on port 42424). I am just looking for some tutorial, you can direct me anywhere - thats all I need. Or you can tell me how to do it step by step, but I know that it takes a lot of time to write answer. I tried googling, but I didn't find anything. And if I did, it was a person who didn't know what the external IP and the port forwarding is so the end of the conversation was: Learn what is port forwarding.

So please, give me some tips how to do it, or direct me somewhere. Thanks!

**The code**

Server:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '10.0.0.140'
    port = 42424
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        data = str(data).upper()
        c.send(data)
    c.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Client:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '10.0.0.140'
    port = 42424 
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host,port))
    message = raw_input("->") 
    while message != 'q':
        s.send(message)
        data = s.recv(1024)
        message = raw_input("->")
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Is your server connected directly to the internet, or does it go through a firewall, router, etc.?

Comment: It's connected through ethernet cable to the router. I don't know anything about firewall.

Comment: The router likely has a built-in firewall that is running. You'll need to look at the manual for that router to see how to add port forwarding. The router provides network address translation (NAT) and it needs to know when port 42424 is accessed from the outside, which machine (behind the router's firewall) it should send the request to.

Comment: As I said, I have one port - 42424 - which is port forwarded. It should be done. I was in my router settings and I set it up.

Comment: What are you trying to get to on your server that you cannot?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand you. What i want to get on my server that I cannot? I just want to connect to the server, send there string and receive the modified string. On the server I want to wait for the connection, then receive string, modify it and send back. Thats all. And I don't know, how to modify my existing source code to be able to do that.

Comment: Can you put an example out of how you have your socket setup to listen on that port?

Comment: Ok, I've just added it into the question. But it can also be done differently.

Comment: The host on your client needs to be the external-facing IP address of your router.

Comment: OMG You are right! I tried it before, but I changed host variable also in my server code and it did not work. But now it does! So simple! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to a server behind a NAT firewall/router, in addition to port forwarding, the client should be directed to the **IP address of the router**. As far as the client is concerned, the IP address of the router *is* the server. The router simply forwards the traffic according to the port forwarding rules.